# Android xml parser to obtain activity and view information

Tags: android, xml, parsing, testing

Are there any 3rd party xml parsers or tools that can parse the Android layout xml files and the manifest file to obtain the list of all the activities and the views under them ?

Comment: `LayoutInflater` and `PackageManager`

Comment: Beyond that, activities do not have a 1:1 relationship to layout resources. An activity can use zero, one, or several layout resources. There is no way, from a manifest entry, to know what layouts an activity might use. This comes on top of the the variations in layouts for different configurations (portrait/landscape, smaller/larger screen, etc.).